# Getting this crash in my App com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild

Tags: android, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting

Can someone help me to find out why this error coming, Lots of crash is happing , in New Release.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1781)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1584)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:24072)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6484)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:24072)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6484)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:24072)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6484)
       at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:148)
       at com.google.android.material.appbar.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:43)
       at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:2172)
```

Please check if anyone facing the same issue.
[image]

Comment: Did you find the cause for this. I am having the same issue